# how to update refered objects in mongoose schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Is there a way by which i can update a refered objet in mongoose i have an id of object from other schema. Actually want a transaction kind of scenario tried multiple things but failed.

Comment: Please add the code and. Make ur question more understandable

Comment: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/transactions.html

Comment: i wanted to know what are the techniques used before transactions were introduced @Vikash Singh